# Why does 'Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector' appear when using the emmeans package?

Tags: r, statistics, emmeans

I am using the `emmeans` package in order to generate estimated means from a linear mixed model that I generated using the `lme4` package. The below is the code I am using to generate my linear mixed model (I opted to exclude the dput() as it is too large and cumbersome):

```r
countsleepdataoff25WAKEANGLMM <- lmer(unlist(propnssANG)~
   as.factor(intoffidhrtime)+
   Daysincedisturb+
   as.factor(intoffidhrtime)*Daysincedisturb+
   (1|Batch)+(1|Batch_Bird_ID)+(1|fdfsrtoff)+
   (1|fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff),
    data=countsleepdataoff25WAKE)
```

In summary, I used the `lmer` command from the `lme4` package, the response variable (`propnssANG`) is a list of proportions to which an arc-sine transformation has been performed. There are 3 fixed effects: `intoffidhrtime` with 5 levels, `Daysincedisturb` with 3 levels and lastly the interaction between the 2. There are also 4 random effects: `Batch` with 4 levels, `Batch_BirdID` with 10 levels, `fdfsrtoff` with 21 levels and `fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff` with 105 levels.

I then used the `emmeans` command to attempt to generate estimated means using the following:

```r
emmeans(countsleepdataoff25WAKEANGLMM,
        WAKEANGgrid)
```

The second argument is required as there is no default but I am unsure if the object I created is appropriate. The object is as follows (again I excluded the `dput()` as it is quite long:

```r
WAKEANGgrid
emmGrid' object with variables:
    intoffidhrtime = 19-21, 21-23, 23-1, 1-3, 3-5
    Daysincedisturb = Disturbed, Recovery, UnDisturbed
Transformation: “unlist”
```

Ultimately, I am met with the error named in the title: 'Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector' and I have absolutely no idea why I am getting this, though I am completely new to `emmeans` so perhaps its something obvious. Any help or suggestions on how I can prevent this error from appearing and be able to generate my estimated means would be greatly appreciated.

Admittedly, I haven't tried much in the way of troubleshooting as I am new to the package and its syntax. I have checked the `?emmeans` help window but I did not find it very helpful and I could not find anything to indicate why I might be getting such an error which by all accounts appears to be more generic than emmeans specific. I would guess there is a problem with my second argument as my first argument is simply the linear mixed model which fits the criteria listed for the first argument of the emmeans function, namely it being a fitted model object that is the result of a call to `lmer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little hard to answer without a reproducible answer, but I'll say what I think is going on. **tl;dr** I think that `WAKEANGgrid` already contains the answers you want — feeding it back into `emmeans` is not using the package as intended ... The second argument to `emmeans()` is supposed to be `specs` (a character vector or formula describing the desired reference grid), not an `emmGrid` object.

First I'll set up an example and run `emmeans` on it. My 'reference grid' (i.e. the values at which the expected marginal means are to be computed) is simpler than yours because there's only one covariate in the model.

```r
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
em1 <- emmeans(fm1, spec = ~ Days, at = list(Days = c(1,4,10)))
## str(em1)
## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     Days =  1,  4, 10
```

Partial print-out of results:

```r
print(em1)
##  Days emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##     1    262  6.79 17      248      276
##     4    293  8.56 17      275      311
##    10    356 16.02 17      322      390
```

If I try to give `em1` as the second (`specs`) argument, I get the same error as you:

```r
 emmeans(fm1, em1)
```

> Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: thanks very much for you answer thats done it for me! At the risk of pushing my luck (and do let me know if I should formally post this as another question), would you happen to know why the (specs) argument only allows for fixed effects to be listed and throws up a completely different error (Error in fac.reduce(RG@linfct[idx, , drop = FALSE]) : 
  could not find function "fac.reduce") when I try to include random effects?

Comment: I don't really know. (1) the `emmeans` vignettes are very extensive, looking there is probably a good idea: (2) random effects really get handled differently. Could be worth a question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) to see if what you want to do even makes sense ... ?